# Xamarin Forms CollectionView OnScroll Hide/Show Element

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a scroll aware header that hide or show header depending on scroll up or down.

I have a grid with a header menu and a collection view :

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *">
    <ContentView x:Name="Header"> ... </ContentView>
    <CollectionView Grid.Row="1"
                    Scrolled="CollectionView_OnScrolled" ... />
</Grid>
```

In the scrolled event i tried to perform something like :

```
void OperationList_Scrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
{
    if (Header.IsVisible && e.VerticalDelta > 0)
    {
        Header.IsVisible = false;
    }
    else if (!Header.IsVisible && e.VerticalDelta < 0)
    {
        Header.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

But it's not very smooth and it blinks. Do you have any ideas to accomplish this properly ?

Comment: Maybe try with fading? Header.FadeTo(0, 1000); Header.IsVisible = false;

Comment: It changes nothing unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use animations to simulate the header visible or not to avoid blinking.

Xaml:

```
  <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Scrolled="CollectionView_OnScrolled">
            <CollectionView.Header>
                <ContentView>
                    <StackLayout x:Name="HeaderView" />
                </ContentView>
            </CollectionView.Header>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Large"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <Frame
    x:Name="HeaderLabelView"
    Margin="16,8,16,8"
    Padding="3"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0, AutoSize, AutoSize"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
    CornerRadius="6"
    HasShadow="True">
            <Label HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </Frame>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
   public partial class Page10 : ContentPage
{
    public Page10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new MonkeyViewModel();
    }

    private void CollectionView_OnScrolled(object sender, ItemsViewScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        var transY = Convert.ToInt32(HeaderLabelView.TranslationY);
        if (transY == 0 &&
            e.VerticalDelta > 15)
        {
            var trans = HeaderLabelView.Height + HeaderLabelView.Margin.Top;

            Task.WhenAll(
                HeaderLabelView.TranslateTo(0, -(trans), 200, Easing.CubicIn),
                HeaderLabelView.FadeTo(0.25, 200));
        }
        else if (transY != 0 &&
                 e.VerticalDelta < 0 &&
                 Math.Abs(e.VerticalDelta) > 10)
        {
            Task.WhenAll(
                HeaderLabelView.TranslateTo(0, 0, 200, Easing.CubicOut),
                HeaderLabelView.FadeTo(1, 200));
        }
    }
}
public class MonkeyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Monkey> Monkeys { get; set; }
    public MonkeyViewModel()
    {
        Monkeys = new ObservableCollection<Monkey>()
        {
            new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"},
             new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="D"}, new Monkey(){ Name="A"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="B"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="C"},
            new Monkey(){ Name="g"},
        };
    }
}

public class Monkey
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```